# how to pattern match 'letrec'

Tags: scheme, pattern-matching, syntax-error, racket, letrec

I am trying to pattern match calls to letrec using match-lambda.  It seems to me that this pattern:

```
(match-lambda
  (`(letrec ((,<var> ,<val>) . (,<vars> ,<vals>)) ,<expr> . ,<exprs>)
   `(<match>))
```

should match calls of the form:

```
(letrec ((<var> <val>) ...) <expr> ...)
```

But, of course, this isn't working.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the `...` syntax in `match-lambda`:

```
(match-lambda
  (`(letrec ((,<var> ,<val>) ...) ,<expr> ...)
    body))
```

Comment: Why? `(x y) and (list `x `y) are identical, aren't they?

Comment: @configurator: I don't think they are equivalent as `match` patterns, at least according to my reading of the documentation.

Comment: They are equivalent objects. The match function accepts the objects only after `read` has already converted them into lists with quoted and unquoted stuff.

Comment: @configurator: The reader macros for quasiquote and unquote just produce `(quasiquote ...)` and `(unquote ...)`; the conversion to `list` and such is done by normal macros which wouldn't be called in `match` patterns.

Comment: @configurator: It appears here that `...` does work in quasipatterns, though, which I do not believe is documented.  I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think the problem might be with the `((,<var> ,<val>) . (,<vars> ,<vals>))`. This is identical to `((,<var> ,<val>) ,<vars> ,<vals>)` which isn't what you want. Perhaps try something like `((,<var> ,<val>) . ,<vars-vals>))`?

---

I also looked into the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html) and it seems like `letrec` shouldn't be part of your expression, and you should possibly use `match-lambda*`.

Try

```
(match-lambda
  (`(((,<var> ,<val>) . ,<vars-vals>) ,<expr> . ,<exprs>)
   `(<match>)))
```

(although of course, I could be wrong)